# Adding a Mailchimp User via Notification Script after Wordpress User subscribes (Membermouse) PHP and API

Tags: php, wordpress, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am working on a MemberMouse subscription Wordpress website. After a User signs up via a webform for a membership, I want to call a script that adds the User to a Mailchimp mailing list WITH a double opt-in. Membermouse offers an integration via Mailchimp, however only with a single opt-in. Therefore, due to government law, I am required to use a double opt-in.

I wrote the following script, that should be called under the condition that once the member is added it sends the following php sript:

```
  <?php

require_once("wp-load.php");
require_once("wp-content/plugins/membermouse/includes/mm-constants.php");
require_once("wp-content/plugins/membermouse/includes/init.php");


// Your Membermouse API URL
$apiUrl = "MYDOMAIN/wp-content/plugins/membermouse/api/request.php";

// Your API key
$apiKey = "my API key";

// Your API secret
$apiSecret = "my API secret";


// ---- GET EVENT TYPE ----
if(!isset($_GET["mm_member_add"]))
{
    // event type was not found, so exit
    exit;
}


// ---- ACCESS DATA ----
// member data
$username = $_GET["username"]; 
$email = $_GET["email"];


            $apiKey1 = 'my Mailchimp API key';
            $listID1 = 'my Mailchimp list ID';

            // MailChimp API URL
            $memberID1 = md5(strtolower($email));
            $dataCenter1 = substr($apiKey1,strpos($apiKey1,'-')+1);
            $url1 = 'https://' . $dataCenter1 . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' . $listID1 . '/members/' . $memberID1;

            // member information
            $json = json_encode([
                    'email_address' => $email,
                    'status'        => 'pending',               
            ]);

            // send a HTTP POST request with curl
            $ch1 = curl_init($url1);
            curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:' . $apiKey1);
            curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
            curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
            curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
            curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
            $result1 = curl_exec($ch1);
            $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch1, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
            curl_close($ch1);
        break;

echo "<pre>".print_r($result1, true)."</pre>";

?>
```

However, it will not respond. The script will be executed.

So far so good. However, I am trying since a couple of days how to write this PHP to get this be working. Additionally, I am not sure if the PHP code is even correct. This was just an assumption.

For references I found this script from membermouse: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/265387542/files/member_notification_script.php

And this script for Mailchimp: https://www.codexworld.com/add-subscriber-to-list-mailchimp-api-php/

I tried to combine these two, however so far without success.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the fast reply @scottcwilson, however I get not responds from this php file.

This is how it looks now:

```
   <?php

require_once("wp-load.php");
require_once("wp-content/plugins/membermouse/includes/mm-constants.php");
require_once("wp-content/plugins/membermouse/includes/init.php");


// Your API URL
$apiUrl = "MYDOMAIN/wp-content/plugins/membermouse/api/request.php";

// Your API key
$apiKey = "My API key";

// Your API secret
$apiSecret = "My API secret";


// ---- GET EVENT TYPE ----
if(!isset($_GET["mm_member_add"]))
{
    // event type was not found, so exit
    exit;
}


// ---- ACCESS DATA ----
// member data
$username = $_GET["username"];
$email = $_GET["email"];


            $apiKey1 = 'Mailchimp API';
            $listID1 = 'Mailchimp List ID';

            // MailChimp API URL
            $memberID1 = md5(strtolower($email));
            $dataCenter1 = substr($apiKey1,strpos($apiKey1,'-')+1);
            $url1 = 'https://' . $dataCenter1 . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' . $listID1 . '/members/';

            // member information
            $json = json_encode([
                    'email_address' => $email,
                    'status'        => 'pending',               
            ]);

            // send a HTTP POST request with curl
            $ch1 = curl_init($url1);
            curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'api_v3:' . $apiKey1);
            curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
            curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
            curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
            $result1 = curl_exec($ch1);
            $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch1, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
            curl_close($ch1);
        break;

echo "<pre>".print_r($result1, true)."</pre>";

?>
```

That is correct how you said, right?

Answer (score 0):

The issues with your current code are:

1) You are supplying the memberid on the URL - this is not what you want for a POST to create a new user.  So do

```
$url1 = 'https://' . $dataCenter1 . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' . $listID1 . '/members/';
```

instead.

2) Some of your cURL setup is wrong.  For your POST fields you want

```
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'api_v3:' . $apiKey1);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
```

get rid of

```
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```